# How to validate image in flutter on pressing submit button?

Tags: firebase, flutter

My every textfield is getting validated. But if the image is not selected and I press submit. It successfully gets uploaded to firestore without an image. But I want to make it stop incase image is null. When i load image it gets display in buildGridView. I guess i need to apply logic somewhere here. That if buildGridView is null. Stop or something. How can i achieve it. Thanks

```
    Widget AddPost() {
        return Form(
          key: _key,
          autovalidate: _validate,
          child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 20.0, 0.0, 0.0),
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  _getPropertyTypeDropDown(),
                  _getPropertyTypeDetailDropDown(),
    
                  UploadPropertyImages(),
                  Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 7),
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                      children: <Widget>[
                          width: 200,
                          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 4,
                          //color: Colors.green,
                          child: buildGridView(),
                        ),
                        RaisedButton(
                          child: Text("Submit"),
                          onPressed: () async {
                            if (_key.currentState.validate()) {
                              _key.currentState.save();
                              Alert(
                                context: context,
                                style: alertStyle,
                                type: AlertType.info,
                                title: "YEY !!",
                                desc: "Your Ad will be displayed soon.",
                                buttons: [
                                  DialogButton(
                                    child: Text(
                                      "Thankyou",
                                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20),
                                    ),
                              //      onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
                                    color: Color.fromRGBO(0, 179, 134, 1.0),
                                    radius: BorderRadius.circular(0.0),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ).show();
                              await runMyFutureGetImagesReference();
                                Navigator.push(
                                    context,
                                    MaterialPageRoute(
                                        builder: (context) => RoleCheck()));
    
                            } else {
                              setState(() {
                                _validate = true;
                              });
                            }
                          },
                          textColor: Colors.black,
                          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 10, 10, 10),
                          splashColor: Colors.grey,
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
    
                  //_showSubmitButton(),
                ],
              )),
        );
      }


  Widget buildGridView() {
    return GridView.count(
      crossAxisCount: 3,
      children: List.generate(images.length, (index) {
        Asset asset = images[index];
        print(asset.getByteData(quality: 100));
        return Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: ClipRRect(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(15)),
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  border: Border.all(color: Colors.blueAccent, width: 2)),
              child: AssetThumb(
                asset: asset,
                width: 300,
                height: 300,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          //  ),
        );
      }),
    );
  }


  Widget UploadPropertyImages() {
    return Container(
        child: Center(
            child: Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 10, 10, 10),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: <Widget>[
          NiceButton(
              width: 250,
              elevation: 8.0,
              radius: 52.0,
              text: "Select Images",
              background: Colors.blueAccent,
              onPressed: () async {
                List<Asset> asst = await loadAssets();
                if (asst.length == 0) {
                  showInSnackBar("No images selected");
                }
                // SizedBox(height: 10,);
                else {
                  showInSnackBar('Images Successfully loaded');
                }
              }),

        ],
      ),
    )));
  }

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
//      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[600],
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      body: Container(

        padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: Form(
          child: ListView(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            children: <Widget>[
              Center(
                child: Text(
                  "Post New Ad",
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),
              ),
              AddPost(),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 16),
              ),
            ], //:TODO: implement upload pictures
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
 }

Future<List<Asset>> loadAssets() async {
    List<Asset> resultList = List<Asset>();
    String error = "No error Detected";

    try {
      resultList = await MultiImagePicker.pickImages(
        maxImages: 10,
        enableCamera: true,
        selectedAssets: images,
        cupertinoOptions: CupertinoOptions(takePhotoIcon: "chat"),
        materialOptions: MaterialOptions(
          actionBarColor: "#abcdef",
          actionBarTitle: "Upload Image",
          allViewTitle: "All Photos",
          useDetailsView: false,
          selectCircleStrokeColor: "#000000",
        ),
      );

      print(resultList.length.toString() + "it is result list");
      /*  print((await resultList[0].getThumbByteData(122, 100)));
      print((await resultList[0].getByteData()));
      print((await resultList[0].metadata));*/
      print("loadAssets is called");
    } on Exception catch (e) {
      error = e.toString();
      print(error.toString() + "on catch of load assest");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

By default Image Picker field is not a form element. You can pick a plugin to do so for your application. Here I am adding one. Please include it and it will give you the scope to validate the picked image as your requirements.

https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker_form_field

You will have to include it in pubspec.yaml and you are ready to use the widget it provides. Just use that like below:

```
ImagePickerFormField(  
  child: Container(  
    height: 40,  
  child: Center(child: Text("Select Photo")),  
  width: double.infinity,  
  decoration: BoxDecoration(  
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8)),  
  border: Border.all(  
            color: Theme.of(context).disabledColor, width: 1)),  
  ),  
  previewEnabled: true,  
  autovalidate: true,  
  context: context,  
  onSaved: (File value) {  
    print("on saved called");  
  },  
  validator: (File value) {  
    if (value == null)  
      return "Please select a photo!";  
 else return null;  },  
  initialValue: null, //File("some source")  
)
```

Comment: I have updated my code. I'm using multi image picker, Can i implement it with multi image picker? If so, then how? Thanks

Comment: No, this image picker doesn't support the multi-image picker, so you will have to build your own custom class to make the Form Field.

Comment: Try this one: https://pub.dev/packages/form_builder_image_picker